# for i, middleware in enumerate(settings.MIDDLEWARE): TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Tags: python, django

I got this error when i try to run

```
python manage.py runserver
```

or any other python manage.py * commands in command line.

but when i tried python manage.py shell it connected without error and gets data from database.

error:

```
 Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x7fa03b7386a8>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tornike/apps/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 227, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/tornike/apps/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 125, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/home/tornike/apps/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 359, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/home/tornike/apps/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 346, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/home/tornike/apps/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 81, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/home/tornike/apps/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/debug_toolbar/apps.py", line 25, in check_middleware
    for i, middleware in enumerate(settings.MIDDLEWARE):
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable




MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware'
)
```

Comment: Did you set the `MIDDLEWARE` setting in your `settings.py`?

Comment: It's obvious from the error that `settings.MIDDLEWARE` is `None`. **Why** it is `None` we can't tell from the information you provided. It is most likely not defined in `settings.py`

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem What do you mean?

Comment: @DeepSpace I updated my question, this are my middlewares in my settings.py. On another pc it works perfectly.

Comment: @I.Jokhadze: no these are the `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES`. That is the "old style". You hould rename it to `MIDDLEWARE`.

Comment: `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` is used in older versions of django.

Comment: Renaming it to middleware will undoubtedly show you other issues, you should use the correct version of django

Comment: Still Does not work. I have same python and django versions on two differenc pc one works and another doesn't. I don't think it is a problem in middleware naming.

Answer (score 0):

The error clears shows that settings.MIDDLEWARE is None but you have posted MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES which are removed from Django 2.0. Please make sure to use MIDDLEWARE in settings.py if the version of django is >=2.0.